# How to run a DalvikVM application with more than 1 DEX files?

Tags: android, dalvik

I just compiled a customized Minecraft server (PC-server running in console) into a .zip file, named `test.zip`, containing `classes.dex` and `classes2.dex`, with sdk-dx tool.

I want to run the application with the "dalvikvm" shell command, but it keeps throwing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test.server.Start`

The path of the .zip file is `/sdcard/Test/test.zip`, and the original main class is `test.server.Start` in `classes.dex`. (I don't think it's modified since I tried dex2jar and the class names remain the same.)

These are the commands I've tried. Non of them works.

`dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/Test/test.zip test.server.Start`

`dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/Test/test.zip/classes.dex;/sdcard/Test/test.zip/classes2.dex test.server.Start`

`dalvikvm -cp "/sdcard/Test/test.zip/classes.dex /sdcard/Test/test.zip/classes2.dex" test.server.Start`

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Why would you expect a PC server to run on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside bigger questions, the Dalvik classpath is a colon-separated list of filenames (e.g. `/sdcard/foo1.jar:/sdcard/foo2.jar`). Each jar/apk contains a single `classes.dex`.  For an APK you'd work around this with [multidex](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html), but for command-line invocation you just need to put each `classes.dex` into its own jarfile.